# FTP upload using python, having trouble with rb mode

Tags: python, zip, ftplib

I have a zip file to upload. I know how to upload it.I open the file with "Rb" mode. When i want to extract the zip file that i uploaded i get an error and files in the ZIP archive are gone, i think that's because of the "Rb" mode . I don't know how to extract my uploaded file.

Here is the code:

```
filename="test.zip"
ftp=ftplib.FTP("ftp.test.com")
ftp.login('xxxx','xxxxx')
ftp.cwd("public_html/xxx")
myfile=open("filepath","rb")
ftp.storlines('STOR ' + filename,myfile)
ftp.quit()
ftp.close()
```

Comment: hi, we'd love to help, but it would be a big step if you can paste the problematic code here, this will help you understand what code you should add : https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: One assumes you need to tell the FTP client/server to use binary mode as well? I think you mean `.storbinary()` maybe? This is discussed in the ftlib API docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is currently using [`ftp.storlines()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ftplib.html?highlight=storlines#ftplib.FTP.storlines) which is intended for use with ASCII files.

For binary files such as ZIP files, you need to use [`ftp.storbinary()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ftplib.html?highlight=storlines#ftplib.FTP.storbinary) instead:

```
import ftplib

filename = "test.zip"    

with open(filename, 'rb') as f_upload:
    ftp = ftplib.FTP("ftp.test.com")
    ftp.login('xxxx', 'xxxxx')
    ftp.cwd("public_html/xxx")
    ftp.storbinary('STOR ' + filename, f_upload)
    ftp.quit()
    ftp.close()
```

When ASCII mode is used on a ZIP file, it will result in an unusable file which is what you were getting.

Comment: wow thanks man.it worked.You did something big for me thank you very much